# R - matching values in a dataframe column to another dataframes row names

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I think this is a fairly challenging data manipulation problem in R, and have struggled constructing a function that can achieve this. The context is organizing basketball players who play different positions into a lineup together, subject to what position each player plays. For some clarity, here is an example of the dataframe I am working with, in two different forms:

```
dput(my_df)
structure(list(Name = c("C.J. McCollum", "DeMar DeRozan", "Jimmy Butler", 
"Jonas Valanciunas", "Kevin Durant", "Markieff Morris", "Pascal Siakam", 
"Pau Gasol"), Pos1 = c("PG", "SG", "SG", "C", "SF", "SF", "PF", 
"C"), Pos2 = c("SG", "", "SF", "", "PF", "PF", "", "")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Pos1", "Pos2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(18L, 33L, 
62L, 68L, 78L, 92L, 106L, 111L))

my_df
                 Name Pos1 Pos2
18      C.J. McCollum   PG   SG
33      DeMar DeRozan   SG     
62       Jimmy Butler   SG   SF
68  Jonas Valanciunas    C     
78       Kevin Durant   SF   PF
92    Markieff Morris   SF   PF
106     Pascal Siakam   PF     
111         Pau Gasol    C     


dput(my_df2)
structure(list(Name = c("C.J. McCollum", "DeMar DeRozan", "Jimmy Butler", 
"Jonas Valanciunas", "Kevin Durant", "Markieff Morris", "Pascal Siakam", 
"Pau Gasol"), Pos1 = c("PG", "SG", "SG", "C", "SF", "SF", "PF", 
"C"), Pos2 = c("SG", "", "SF", "", "PF", "PF", "", ""), PG = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SG = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SF = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), PF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), C = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), BackupG = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BackupF = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Man8 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Pos1", "Pos2", "PG", "SG", "SF", "PF", "C", "BackupG", "BackupF", 
"Man8"), row.names = c(18L, 33L, 62L, 68L, 78L, 92L, 106L, 111L
), class = "data.frame")


my_df2
                 Name Pos1 Pos2 PG SG SF PF C BackupG BackupF Man8
18      C.J. McCollum   PG   SG  1  1  0  0 0       1       0    1
33      DeMar DeRozan   SG       0  1  0  0 0       1       0    1
62       Jimmy Butler   SG   SF  0  1  1  0 0       1       1    1
68  Jonas Valanciunas    C       0  0  0  0 1       0       0    1
78       Kevin Durant   SF   PF  0  0  1  1 0       0       1    1
92    Markieff Morris   SF   PF  0  0  1  1 0       0       1    1
106     Pascal Siakam   PF       0  0  0  1 0       0       1    1
111         Pau Gasol    C       0  0  0  0 1       0       0    1
```

In a basketball lineup, we want 1 player set for each of the 5 positions in basketball (PG, SG, PF, SF, C), we also want 1 backup guard (a PG or SG is a guard), 1 backup forward (a PF or FS is a forward), and an 8th player who can play any position. With this group of 8 players, we could construct the lineup in this way:

```
                        Name
         PG    C.J. McCollum  
         SG    DeMar DeRozan  
         PF    Kevin Durant  
         SF    Markieff Morris  
          C    Pau Gasol 
   Backup G    Jimmy Butler 
   Backup F    Pascal Siakam
    8th Man    Jonas Valanciunas
```

Ofcourse there is some flexibility with this (Kevin Durant and Markieff Morris could have been switched, in fact theres several players who could have switched spots in the 2nd dataframe). I would like to be able to organize my_df into this 2nd dataframes format in a fairly quick matter, something that takes the Pos1 and Pos2 columns from my_df, is able to check the rownames of the 2nd dataframe, and then fill in the player names.

There is a puzzle aspect to this however. Of note is that, not all players have a second position, but those players who do have a second position can be listed at either of the two positions. (for example, Jimmy Butler can be set as a SG, a SF, a Backup G, a backup F, or the 8th man, whereas Pau Gasol can only be set as a C, or as the 8th man). Additionally, while C.J. McCollum is listed as a PG and SG, he is the only player in my_df who is listed as a PG, and therefore must go in the PG row of the second dataframe.

Any thoughts are appreciated with this! I can provide more context if needed.

(edit: potentially editing my_df, adding Pos3, Pos4, Pos5 columns for whether a player can be a backup G, backup F, or 8th Man, may help as well, and is something I am currently working with).

Edit - see [Simplify this grid such that each row and column has 1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068012/r-simplify-this-grid-such-that-each-row-and-column-has-1-value) for a revised version of my question, which is a simpler problem to solve but will give me a solution to this question!

Answer (score 0):

This approach is guaranteed to return a result if there is one, in fact it will return all viable combinations.

```
st<-as.matrix(my_df2[4:dim(my_df2)[2]]) # Make a numeric matrix

## allCombinationsAux may not be necessary if you are using a combinatorics library
allCombinationsAux<-function(z,nreg,x){
    if(sum(nreg)>1){
        innerLoop<-do.call(rbind,lapply(x[nreg&(z!=x)], test1,nreg&(z!=x),x))
        ret<-cbind(z,innerLoop )
    }
    else{
        ret<-x[nreg]
    }
    ret
}

## Find all the possible row combinations for the matrix
combs<-do.call(rbind,lapply(x,function(y) allCombinationsAux(y,y!=x,x)))

## Identify which combinations are valid
inds<-which(apply(combs,1,function(x) sum(diag(st[x,]))==8))

## Select valid matricies
validChoices<-lapply(inds,function(x) st[combs[x,],])
```

1. Make a matrix out of `my_df2`
2. Find all possible matrix substitutions
3. Iterate through all possible matrices testing if the diags are all 1
4. Select those matrices that are valid

To get the output to look like your example you can run

```
validChoices<-lapply(inds,function(x) {
    matr<-st[combs[x,],]
    retVal<-data.frame(Name=my_df2[combs[x,],"Name"])
    rownames(retVal)<-colnames(matr)
    retVal
    })
```