# Simplify this grid such that each row and column has 1 value

Tags: r

Example code here:

```
> temp2
  a b c d e f g h
i 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
j 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
k 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
l 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
m 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
n 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
o 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
p 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1

> dput(temp2)
structure(list(a = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), d = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0), e = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), f = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), g = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), h = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("i", "j", "k", "l", 
"m", "n", "o", "p"))
```

I have this 8x8 grid of 1s and 0s. I need to solve for some grid where each row and each column has exactly one 1 and the rest 0s, but the 1 has to be in a place where the original grid has a 1. It's almost like a sudoku question but not exactly. Any thoughts on how to get started?

I would need some function that can do this for a general grid, not simply this specific one. We can assume that there's always a solution grid, given some starting grid.

Thanks!

Edit: a valid solution

```
> temp3
  a b c d e f g h
i 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
k 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
l 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
m 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
n 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
o 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

EDIT2: given that there's only 8! unique solutions for any grid, i may attempt a brute force / matching approach.

Comment: yes will update with a sufficient result

Comment: Will the matrix always be square?

Comment: yes it will be square

Comment: valid solution posted, although note that this is not a unique solution, although like i said there will always be at least one valid solution.

Comment: it will always be square AND it will always be 8x8

Comment: Thank you everybody for many good solutions to this problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be solved as a transportation problem or as an integer programming problem.  We also show a one-line solution using only base R which generates random matrices for which each row and each columns column sums to 1 filtering out and returning the ones satisfying the additional constraints that each element of the solution matrix be less than or equal to the corresponding element of `temp2`.

**1) transportation problem** Using `lp.transport` in lpSolve we can solve it in one statement:

```
library(lpSolve)

res <- lp.transport(as.matrix(temp2), "max", 
  rep("=", 8), rep(1, 8), rep("=", 8), rep(1, 8), integers = 0:1)

res
## Success: the objective function is 8

soln <- array(res$solution, dim(temp2))

# verify

all(colSums(soln)==1) && all(rowSums(soln)==1) && all(temp2>=soln) && all(soln %in% 0:1)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) integer programming**

If X is the solution we have specified the row and column constraints but have not specified the X <= temp2 constraints since they will be satisfied automatically as no solution putting a 1 where a temp2 0 is can have the maximum objective of 8.

```
library(lpSolve)

n <- nrow(temp2)
obj <- unlist(temp2)
const_row <- t(sapply(1:n, function(i) c(row(temp2)) == i)) # each row sums to 1
const_col <- t(sapply(1:n, function(i) c(col(temp2)) == i)) # each col sums to 1
const.mat <- rbind(const_row, const_col)
res <- lp("max", obj, const.mat, "=", 1, all.bin = TRUE)
res
## Success: the objective function is 8

soln <- array(res$solution, dim(temp2))

# verify

all(colSums(soln)==1) && all(rowSums(soln)==1) && all(temp2>=soln) && all(soln %in% 0:1)
## [1] TRUE
```

(Note that by the same argument we could have relaxed the problem to a linear programming problem provided we add 0 <= soln[i, j] <= 1 constraints since by the same argument that allowed us to omit the soln[i, j] <= temp2[i, j] constraints the maximization will force the soln elements to be 0 or 1 anyways.)

**2a)** This approach is longer but does spell out the X <= temp2 constraints explicitly:

```
n <- nrow(temp2)
obj <- numeric(n*n)
const1 <- diag(n*n) # soln[i,j] <= temp2[i,j]
const2 <- t(sapply(1:n, function(i) c(row(temp2)) == i)) # each row sums to 1
const3 <- t(sapply(1:n, function(i) c(col(temp2)) == i)) # each col sums to 1
const.mat <- rbind(const1, const2, const3)
const.dir <- rep(c("<=", "="), c(n*n, 2*n))
const.rhs <- c(unlist(temp2), rep(1, 2*n))

res <- lp("max", obj, const.mat, const.dir, const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
res
## Success: the objective function is 0

soln <- array(res$solution, dim(temp2))

# verify

all(colSums(soln)==1) && all(rowSums(soln)==1) && all(temp2>=soln) && all(soln %in% 0:1)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2b)** Note that if X is the solution matrix then in X <= temp2 only the positions of X corresponding to zeros in temp2 actually constrain so we could eliminate any constraint corresponding to a 1 in temp2 in the (2a) solution.  With this change all constraints become equality constraints.

```
n <- nrow(temp2)
obj <- numeric(n*n)
const1 <- diag(n*n)[unlist(temp2) == 0, ]
const2 <- t(sapply(1:n, function(i) c(row(temp2)) == i)) # each row sums to 1
const3 <- t(sapply(1:n, function(i) c(col(temp2)) == i)) # each col sums to 1
const.mat <- rbind(const1, const2, const3)
const.dir <- "="
const.rhs <- c(numeric(nrow(const1)), rep(1, 2*n))

res <- lp("max", obj, const.mat, const.dir, const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
res
## Success: the objective function is 0

soln <- array(res$solution, dim(temp2))

# verify

all(colSums(soln)==1) && all(rowSums(soln)==1) && all(temp2>=soln) && all(soln %in% 0:1)
## [1] TRUE
```

In fact, we could go further and remove the variables that correspond to zero elements of `temp2`.

**3) r2dtable**  Here we use `rd2table to generate 10,000 8x8 tables whose rows and columns sum to 1 and then filter them to pick out only those satisfying the  X < temp2 constrainsts.  With`temp2` from the question and the random seed shown has found 3 solutions.  If with different inputs it finds no solutions then try generating a higher number of random proposals.  This approach does not use any packages.

```
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
Filter(function(x) all(x <= temp2), r2dtable(10000, rep(1, 8), rep(1, 8)))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 6):

A brute-force way:

```
m = as.matrix(temp2)
w = data.frame(which(m == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))
combos = as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, with(w, split(col, row))))
combos[ apply(combos, 1, function(x) !anyDuplicated(x)), ]


      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 [1,] 1 6 2 8 7 3 4 5
 [2,] 1 2 6 8 7 3 4 5
 [3,] 1 6 2 8 3 7 4 5
 [4,] 1 2 6 8 3 7 4 5
 [5,] 1 6 2 8 4 3 7 5
 [6,] 1 2 6 8 4 3 7 5
 [7,] 1 6 2 8 3 4 7 5
 [8,] 1 2 6 8 3 4 7 5
 [9,] 1 6 2 5 7 3 4 8
[10,] 1 2 6 5 7 3 4 8
[11,] 1 6 2 5 3 7 4 8
[12,] 1 2 6 5 3 7 4 8
[13,] 1 6 2 5 4 3 7 8
[14,] 1 2 6 5 4 3 7 8
[15,] 1 6 2 5 3 4 7 8
[16,] 1 2 6 5 3 4 7 8
```

OP claims to only ever need to handle an 8x8 grid, so I guess this performs well enough. Each row of the result is a solution. The first row says that (1,1), (2,6), (3,2) ... is a solution.

---

A variation using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
m = as.matrix(temp2)
comboDT = setDT(melt(m))[ value == 1, do.call(CJ, split(Var2, Var1)) ][, 
  rid := .I ][, melt(.SD, id="rid", variable.name="row", value.name="col")]

setkey(comboDT, rid)
comboDT[ .( comboDT[, !anyDuplicated(col), by=rid][(V1), rid]) ]
```

Comment: So much better than my solution, since you have check significantly fewer combos.

Comment: @AlexanderGriffith Thanks. I think there must be far more efficient ways than this too.

Answer (score 1):

this works. Let grid be my grid (temp2 from above). then this will return a grid that works

```
# create random sufficient grid
  counter = 0
  while(2 > 1) {
    counter = counter + 1
    if(counter == 10000) {
      break
    }
    rand_grid = matrix(0, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
    indices_avail = seq(1,8,by=1)
    for(i in 1:8) {
      k = sample(indices_avail, 1)
      rand_grid[i, k] = 1
      indices_avail = indices_avail[indices_avail != k]
    }
    if(sum(grid[which(rand_grid == 1)]) == 8) {
      break
    }
    print(counter)
  }
```

Comment: Will return it with certainty or some probability? I wouldn't expect to see `sample` here.

Comment: I believe with certainty. We are given the fact that a solution exists. I simply use sample() as a way to create a random_grid to compare with my own.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will return all valid combinations. First find all matrix row combinations. Then search through exhaustively. This method would have to be improved if your matrix size increased. One simple improvement would be to run the diag test in parallel.

```
st<-as.matrix(temp2) # make sure we are working with matrices
## This method will return all possible matrices of combinations
## in essence if you have diag(matr) = width matrix than you have
## a valid choice


## Helper function to build all combinations, there may be better way to
## do this but it gets the job done
allCombinationsAux<-function(z,nreg,x){
    if(sum(nreg)>1){
        innerLoop<-do.call(rbind,lapply(x[nreg&(z!=x)], test1,nreg&(z!=x),x))
        ret<-cbind(z,innerLoop )
    }
    else{
        ret<-x[nreg]
    }
    ret
}

## Build all of the combinations of possible matrices
combs<-do.call(rbind,lapply(x,function(y) allCombinationsAux(y,y!=x,x)))

## iterate through all the possible combinations of matrices, to find out
## which ones have 1s throughout the  diag
inds<-which(apply(combs,1,function(x) sum(diag(st[x,]))==8))

lapply(inds,function(x) st[combs[x,],])
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are great answers already here for the brute-force approach and actually using math, just for kicks, here's a version that guesses and checks lags of the non-matching columns. For the example in question, it actually turns out to be quite quick, and as a bonus, you could find a new answer on any particular run! How fun! To the code:

```r
set.seed(47)    # remove this to have more fun

mat.in <- as.matrix(temp2)  # we'll work in matrices
mat.out <- diag(8)  # a starting guess
dimnames(mat.out) <- dimnames(mat.in)  # make our answer pretty

iteration <- 1  # for kicks, a loop counter

while (any((mat.out != mat.in)[as.logical(mat.out)])) {
    mat.ref <- mat.out
    mat.out <- mat.out[, sample(8)]  # make this deterministic if you like
    inner <- 1  # don't repeat yourself (too much)
    while (any(mat.out != mat.ref) & inner <= 8) {
        mat.ref <- mat.out

        # find non-matching indices and lag those columns
        to.lag <- which((mat.out != mat.in)[as.logical(mat.out)])
        i <- 1:8
        i[to.lag] <- c(to.lag[length(to.lag)], to.lag[-length(to.lag)])
        mat.out <- mat.out[, i]

        cat(inner, " ")  # let's see what it does
        inner <- inner + 1
    }
    print(iteration)  # whoo, scrolling numbers
    iteration <- iteration + 1
}
## 1  2  3  [1] 1
## 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  [1] 2
## 1  2  [1] 3
## 1  2  3  [1] 4
```

which, for this particular seed returns

```
mat.out
##   a c e g d b f h
## i 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
## j 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
## k 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
## l 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
## m 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
## n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
## o 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
## p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

It could certainly be optimized further, but it's already pretty quick (without the printing, which slows it down):

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 let's guess 137.796 383.6445 838.2327 693.819 1163.08 2510.436   100
```

running all 100 times in a fraction of a second. It's quite a bit faster than actual guessing (chopping out the inner loop):

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min       lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
    guess smart 148.997  349.916   848.6314   588.162  1085.841   3117.78   100  a 
 actually guess 322.458 7341.961 31197.1237 20012.969 47677.501 160250.02   100   b
```

Note, though, that luck plays a role here, and if there are fewer solutions, it will take longer. If there are no solutions, it will run forever. It could, of course, be optimized to avoid such a fate by making sure it doesn't reuse the same starting permutation provided by `sample(8)` (a good idea regardless, which I deemed superfluous here as it only runs through a handful of permutations each run anyway). Hack away.